# Is there an equivalent to Java Media Framework in C#?

Tags: c#, jmf, equivalent

Is there an equivalent to [Java Media Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/) in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like [DirectShow .NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/).  There are also links there to the related [Media Foundation .NET](http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/) and [Windows Media .NET](http://windowsmedianet.sourceforge.net/) projects.

Media Foundation is a successor to DirectShow for Windows Vista and beyond.  If you need to target XP you will need to use DirectShow.

Answer (score 0):

[DirectX 9.0 for Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb318659(VS.85).aspx)

> DirectX is a set of low-level
>   application programming interfaces
>   (APIs) for creating games and other
>   high-performance multimedia
>   applications. It includes support for
>   high-performance 2-D and 3-D graphics,
>   sound, and input.

[Introducing the New Managed Direct3D Graphics API in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164112.aspx)

> DirectX 9.0 for Managed Code is made
>   up of the following major components.
>
> - Direct3D Graphics provides a single API that you can use for 3-D graphics
>     programming.
> - DirectDraw provides direct low-level access to video memory for high-speed
>     rendering. Deprecated.
> - DirectInput provides support for a variety of input devices, including
>     full support for force-feedback
>     technology.
> - DirectPlay provides support for multiplayer networked games.
>     Deprecated.
> - DirectSound provides support for playing and capturing prerecorded
>     digital samples.
> - Audio Video Playback allows for playback and simple control of audio
>     and video media.

As another poster has pointed out, if you do not need such fine grain control, then there are standard Windows components to playback media.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Media Player SDK has a [.NET Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564585(VS.85).aspx) that you can drop onto forms.  Additionally, .NET 3.0 and newer has a [WPF control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) for media.